# I want to switch the screen when the Label named New Account is pressed, but the application keeps crashing. Can you help me?

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, uikit, action

```
    lazy var newAccountLabel: UILabel = {
    let newAccountLabel = UILabel()
    newAccountLabel.text = " New Account"
    newAccountLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: LoginViewController.self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.newAccountLabelTapped(_:)))
    newAccountLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    newAccountLabel.textColor = .systemGray
    return newAccountLabel
}()
```

> The creation of the label I want to click on.

```
@objc func newAccountLabelTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    
    let goToVc = RegisterViewController()
    self.present(goToVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> The action function that the transition should be.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `LoginViewController.self` with `self`

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.newAccountLabelTapped(_:)))
```

Comment: Sh_Khan, good catch. I missed the fact the OP was trying to make the **class** the target. (Voted.)